# Argparse for Golang

Tags: go

### Reasons

I'm recently learning Go with various exercises (might be more questions coming in the future)

However, I'm quite annoyed with the default argument parsing module in Go [flag](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) as it doesn't satisfy my needs most of the time.

So as a learning exercise I went ahead and created a simplified clone of python's argparse module. It isn't a 1 on 1 clone and I don't want it to be.

### Module

```
package argparse

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "reflect"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type Argument struct {
    ShortFlag, LongFlag, Help string
    Type, Default interface{}
    Required bool
}

type Argparse struct {
    Programme, Description string
    Arguments []Argument
}

func (p *Argparse) findArgument(arg string) *Argument {
    if !strings.Contains(arg, "-") {
        return nil
    }

    for _, a := range p.Arguments {
        if a.ShortFlag == arg[1:] || a.LongFlag == arg[2:] {
            return &a
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func (p *Argparse) Parse() map[string]interface{}  {
    args := make(map[string]interface{})
    osArgs := os.Args

    for _, a := range osArgs[1:] {
        if "-h" == a || "--help" == a {
            p.Help()
        }
    }

    for i := 1; i < len(osArgs); i++ {
        a := p.findArgument(osArgs[i])
        if a != nil {
            _type := reflect.TypeOf(a.Type)
            switch _type.Kind() {
                case reflect.String:
                    if len(osArgs) == i + 1 {
                        fmt.Println("[ERROR] Didn't supply the argument for", a.LongFlag)
                        os.Exit(3)
                    }
                    args[a.LongFlag] = osArgs[i + 1]
                    i += 1
                case reflect.Int:
                    if len(osArgs) == i + 1 {
                        fmt.Println("[ERROR] Didn't supply the argument for", a.LongFlag)
                        os.Exit(3)
                    }                   
                    retValue, err := strconv.Atoi(osArgs[i + 1])
                    if err != nil {
                        fmt.Println(osArgs[i + 1], "is not an integer")
                        os.Exit(3)
                    }
                    args[a.LongFlag] = retValue
                    i += 1
                case reflect.Bool:
                    args[a.LongFlag] = true
                default:
                    fmt.Println("[ERROR]: Flag", a.LongFlag, "is of type", _type.Kind(), "which is not supported")
                    os.Exit(3)
            }
        }
    }

    for _, arg := range p.Arguments {
        if _, f := args[arg.LongFlag]; !f {
            if arg.Required && arg.Default == nil {
                fmt.Println("[ERROR]: Flag", arg.LongFlag, "is required and not set")
                os.Exit(3)
            }

            args[arg.LongFlag] = arg.Default
        }
    }
    return args
}

func (p *Argparse) AddArgument(arg Argument) {
    if arg.LongFlag == "" {
        fmt.Println("[ERROR]: LongFlag must be set")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    if arg.Type == nil {
        fmt.Println("[ERROR]: Type must be set")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    p.Arguments = append(p.Arguments, arg)
}

func (p *Argparse) Help() {
    if p.Programme == "" {
        p.Programme = os.Args[0]
    }

    fmt.Print("Usage ", p.Programme, "\n\n")
    fmt.Print(p.Description, "\n\n")
    for _, a := range p.Arguments {
        fmt.Print("\t", "-" + a.ShortFlag, ", ", "--" + a.LongFlag, "\t", a.Help, "\n")
    }
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

### Implementation

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "argparse"
)

func parseArguments() map[string]interface{} {
    parser := argparse.Argparse {
        Description: "Testing argparse logic",
    }

    parser.AddArgument(
        argparse.Argument {
            ShortFlag: "t", LongFlag: "text", Type: "string", 
            Required: true, Help: "A line of text",
        },
    )

    parser.AddArgument(
        argparse.Argument {
            ShortFlag: "e", LongFlag: "enc", Type: false, 
            Help: "Something else", Default: false,
        },
    )

    return parser.Parse()
}

func main() {
    args := parseArguments()
    for k, v := range args {
        fmt.Println("Argument:", k, "=", v)
    }
}
```

### Example

```
$ ./test -t "-e"
Argument: text = -e
Argument: enc = false
```

As mentioned I'm fairly new to the language so any recommendation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could this help: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/akamensky/argparse?